# pygtk minimizing and maximizing window

Tags: window, pygtk, window-managers

I'm using pygtk and once I minimize window (iconyfy it) window manager uses its animation to do that. Before i minimize it (user can't do that;no minimize button, just from code) it is on right hand size of desktop. Now when user clicks on tackbar icon wm shows up window, but it's not on right hand side, it goes to the center of the screen. Is there a way to remove this behavior? I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I've never used python or gtk, but couldn't you just set the window to the correct position sometime during or after the minimization?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by remove this behavior? Window managers are free to place windows where they deem fit (in most cases), as pointed by @Jwosty you can make use of [`gtk.Window.move`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--move) to request WM to move the window to certain position.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying but when you click on taskbar icon it first shows window on center of screen and then moves it where I want it to be. I need a way to show it immediately at right position. I looks very bad this way, it flash on center and then shows at right hand side.

Comment: Maybe you could hide the whole window when iconifying, then on clicking on taskbar icon first move the window, then show it.